# Nature of complex fixed point (in one dimension)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers, dynamical-systems

Suppose we have an ordinary differential equation:

$\dfrac{dx}{dt} = f(x)$

To determine the value of the fixed/critical/equilibrium point(s), we set $\dfrac{dx}{dt} = 0$, that is, we calculate the values of $x$ which satisfy the equation $f(x) = 0$.

Suppose a fixed point exists called $x_*$.

To determine the nature of this fixed point, we calculate $\dfrac{dx}{dt}$ to the left and to the right of it. If $\dfrac{dx}{dt}>0$ to the left of $x_*$ and $\dfrac{dx}{dt}<0$ to the right of $x_*$ we say that it is stable. Otherwise, it is unstable.

The analysis above was limited to real fixed points, that is $x_*$ $\in \mathbb{R}$.

How may we generalise and extend the above analysis and determine the nature of complex fixed points in one dimension?

So, suppose we have:
$\dfrac{dx}{dt} = 1 + x^2$. The fixed point is complex and I cannot explain its nature.

Comment: Perhaps you could analyse the system $u' = 1+u^2-v^2$, $v'=2 uv$ instead?

Answer (score 1):

You have first to decide what is your phase space:

If it is $\mathbb R$, then $x'=1+x^2$ has no constant solutions (what you call fixed points).

If it is $\mathbb C$, then you need to solve $z'=1+z^2$ (this is better) or to transform it in $x'=1+x^2-y^2, \ y'=2xy$ and proceed from there.

Comment: I'm trying my best to proceed from where you left the answer and I fear I'm embarrassingly off the mark. Anyway, here goes. The fixed points of the revised system of your two differential equations gives me $(-i,0)$, $(i,0)$, $(0,-1)$ and $(0,1)$. I then calculate the Jabobian of $A$, i.e. $J(A)$ at each of those fixed points and subtract from it $I\lambda$ where $I$ is an identity matrix. Since these values all give me pure imaginary values for all $\lambda$ at all fixed points, I then say that the fixed point in the original question is a centre. I might need more guidance

Comment: We don't know what is your phase space. If it is $\mathbb C$, then $x$ and $y$ are real numbers (you seem to be taking $x,y\in\mathbb C$). But it is much better to write $z'/(1+z^2)=(\arctan z)'$.